# get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url' while using HTMLsession

Tags: python

Hi I am getting the error get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url' I am using HTMLsession for importing the data from a website. sharing the code below.
'''

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
session=HTMLSession
url="https://pureportal.coventry.ac.uk/en/organisations/coventry-university/publications/"
def data(url):
  r=session.get(url)
  r.html.render(sleep=1)
  soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,"html.parser")
  return soup
def Allpage(soup):
    page=soup.find("li",{"class":"step"})
    if not page.find("li",{"class":"next"}):
        url="https://pureportal.coventry.ac.uk/" + str(page.find("li",{"class":"step"})).find("a")["href"]
        return url
    else:
        return
while True:
    getdata=data(url)
    url=Allpage(getdata)
    print(URL)
```

'''

TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Answer (score 1):

`session` should be *instance of* `HTMLSession`, consider that

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession
session.get("http://www.example.com")
```

gives `TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'` whilst

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
session.get("http://www.example.com")
```

works without errors (last line returns `<Response [200]>`)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to **instantiate HTMLSession**, so the 'get' method acts strangely. Just change your session declaration to :

```py
session=HTMLSession()
```